# Select first first child element in XSLT

Tags: xslt

The `<graphic>` element to be used from the input XML should be the first child element of the `<body>` element. How Can I check this using XSLT

Input :

```
<body>
  <graphic>Image</graphic>
  <p>Text</p>
</body>
```

Output of above should be `true`. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="body">
      <xsl:if test="*[1][local-name()='graphic']"><xsl:text>Yes</xsl:text></xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Why did you post two answers? You could have edited this into your first answer

Comment: @Ajeet Singh please check your code (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq7g)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try it**

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="body/*[1][local-name()='graphic']">
            <xsl:text>True</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>False</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a result of `true` or `false`, you can do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:value-of select="name(*[1])='graphic'"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="if(body/*[1][self::graphic]) then 'True' else 'False'"/>
</xsl:template>
```